# RuntimeError: There's no handler for [insert_filed_name] in the 'validate' domain

Tags: python, cerberus

I am using `cerberus` v1.3.2 with `python-3.8` stable to validate json data that will be used to send http requests. I am having an issue using the `dependencies` rule. My objects have a field `request_type` and an optional field `payload` that contains more data. Only objects that have a `request_type` in `['CREATE', 'AMEND']` have a `payload`. When I run the validation, I get an error related to one of the fields in `payload`. Here is the code I'm running:

```
from cerberus import Validator

request = {
    "request_type": "CREATE",
    "other_field_1": "whatever",
    "other_field_2": "whatever",
    "payload": {
        "id": "123456",
        "jobs": [
            {
                "duration": 1800,
                "other_field_1": "whatever",
                "other_field_2": "whatever"
            }
        ]
    }
}

schema = {
    'request_type': {
        'type': 'string',
        'allowed': ['CREATE', 'CANCEL', 'AMEND'],
        'required': True,
        'empty': False
    },
    'other_field_1': {'type': 'string', },
    'other_field_2': {'type': 'string', },
    'payload': {
        'required': False,
        'schema': {
            'id': {
                'type': 'string',
                'regex': r'[A-Za-z0-9_-]`',
                'minlength': 1, 'maxlength': 32,
                'coerce': str
            },
            'jobs': {
                'type': 'list',
                'schema': {
                    'duration': {
                        'type': 'integer', 'min': 0,
                        'required': True, 'empty': False,
                    },
                    'other_field_1': {'type': 'string', },
                    'other_field_2': {'type': 'string', },
                }
            }
        },
        'dependencies': {'request_type': ['CREATE', 'AMEND']},
    }
}

validator = Validator(schema, purge_unknown=True)
if validator.validate(request):
    print('The request is valid.')
else:
    print(f'The request failed validation: {validator.errors}')
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
"RuntimeError: There's no handler for 'duration' in the 'validate' domain."
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

For context, I managed to make the validation work by using the exact same rules, but instead of using `dependencies`, I have two separate schemas named `payload_schema` and `no_payload_schema`. In `payload_schema` I set the allowed values for `request_type` to `['CREATE', 'AMEND']`, and in `no_payload_schema` I set the allowed values to `['CANCEL']`. I run the validation on both schemas and if neither of them passes, I raise an error. This sounds a bit hacky and I'd like to understand how I could use the `dependencies` rule to do that.

Comment: Can you add an example record of the data you are validating?

Comment: Just edited the question: the code is now a single block and you should be able to run it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mind the [difference between schema](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#schema-dict) being used for mappings and sequences. The `jobs` field's value won't be checked as mapping since you require it to be of `list` type. You'll need this pattern:

```py
{"jobs": 
  {
    {"type": "list", "schema": 
      {
        "type": "dict", "schema": {"duration": ...}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This ambiguity of the `schema` rule will be addressed in the next major release of Cerberus. For the sake of readability one may use [schema- and rule set-registries](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/schemas.html#registries) with complex validation schemas.

It is generally advisable to ask with minimum examples for support.